# trigger a function with name as a variable name

Tags: jquery

```js
$('.dgok').click(function(){
var fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
console.log(fn); // abc
fn();
});

function abc(){
console.log('abc');
}
```

```css
.dgok{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dgok' data-fn='abc'>OK</div>
```

Result:  `Error fn is not a function...`

Is there a way to do this?

lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any variable or function in the **global scope** with a string. It's not usually recommended, but is possible:

```
window[string]();
```

Here, `window` is an object with every global variable being an attribute.

**EDIT**

It is not recommended because global variables can cause name conflicts, and can be accessed from anywhere, from any function or file, making bugs harder to track down.

By the way, you could use the built-in HTML `onclick` attribute instead, like so:

```js
function abc(){
console.log('abc');
}
```

```css
.dgok{
cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dgok' onclick='abc()'>OK</div>
```

Comment: why it is not recommended, pls?

Comment: @puerto Global variables in general aren't recommended because they can be accessed anywhere, from any function or file. This can cause problems such as name conflicts, and makes bugs hard to track down. By the way, you could just use the built-in HTML `onclick`, for example: `<div class='dgok' onclick='abc()'>OK</div>`.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically accessing a function name is usually a code smell, but if your `abc` is on the top level, you can access `window[fnName]`, where `fnName` is a string containing the function name. Precise variable names are *important* - your `fn` is *not* a function, but a string, so best to call it something that makes it clearer that it's a string (less chance of confusing yourself by trying to invoke it). For example:

```js
$('.dgok').click(function() {
  var fnName = $(this).attr('data-fn');
  window[fnName]();
});
function abc() {
  console.log('abc');
}
```

```css
.dgok {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dgok' data-fn='abc'>OK</div>
```

If your `abc` is *not* on the top level, `window[fnName]` won't work - use an object indexed by function names instead:

```js
(() => {
  const fns = {
    abc: () => console.log('abc')
  };
  $('.dgok').click(function() {
    var fnName = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    fns[fnName]();
  });
})();
```

```css
.dgok {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='dgok' data-fn='abc'>OK</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This would work:

```
// find elements
$('.dgok').click(function(){
var fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
//console.log(fn);
var execute=(fn);
console.log(execute);

});

function abc(){
console.log('abc');
}
```

Remember that (fn) executes the function... when you assign it to something, it calls it and sets the variable to the return value (in this case execute).